# XSLT- copy value from parent to child based on value of particular element

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Based on input xml below,If the orderitem is of type "desktop" at the parent level then update the price of all child orderitem same as Parent price.
orderitem is recursive and can have 1-n orderitems inside. For simiplicity i considered 3 children and 1 parent orderitem.
I have another question which involves dependency, i.e if parent has an objectid and it matches objectid of child then update the price. But, i will ask as a new question once this is resolved.Thanks.

```
<listoforders>
 <Orderitem>
  <name>Desktop</name>
  <place>NZ</place>
  <price>120</price>
  <Orderitem>
   <name>Desktop2</name>
   <place>NZ</place>
   <price>130</price>
  </Orderitem>
  <Orderitem>
   <name>Desktop3</name>
   <place>NZ</place>
   <price>130</price>
  </Orderitem>
 </Orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

Result:

```
<listoforders>
  <Orderitem>
  <name>Desktop</name>
  <place>NZ</place>
  <price>120</price>
  <Orderitem>
   <name>Desktop2</name>
   <place>NZ</place>
   <price>120</price>
  </Orderitem>
  <Orderitem>
   <name>Desktop3</name>
   <place>NZ</place>
   <price>120</price>
  </Orderitem>
 </Orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

Appears simple, but i am  not able to do it via the identity rule. Do i need to use for-each here?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="orderitem[name='Desktop']/price">
 <xsl:variable name="temp" select="*[(self::price)]"/>
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:value-of select=$temp </xsl:value-of>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[(child::price)]"/> 
 </xsl:copy>    
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Krish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price[../../name='Desktop']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../../price"/>         
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, can you kindly help me understand this please. What i understood is ..we are matching for price element, which has name as 'Desktop' two generations upwards and then copying the price by selecting parent level price. I am bit confused on how it works. Thanks.

Comment: We are matching `Price` whose grandparent's name is "Desktop", and then copying the price from the grandparent. This is the same thing as changing the price of `Orderitem` whose parent's name is "Desktop". We only want to change the price, so the smart thing to do is match it directly, not its parent.

Comment: So how does it  apply the price to its child elements (and not price in another orderitem). Is it implicit? It doesnt necesarily be a grandparent, it can be parent as well.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking there. It only matches `Price` whose grandparent's name is "Desktop". All other `Price` elements are matched by the *identity transform* template and copied as is.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, i fail to understand how the price is getting modified with above rule; since i do not see any explicit instruction which says,update the 'price' of  all elements which are children of 'orderitem' with name Hardware with parent's price.  Did i misunderstood something here?

Comment: Oh, i re-read your answer. I think i got it, I will try with few samples. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: :i am using online tool to check my transformation.
 In reality i need to use spring framework  to transform my xml based on xslt input[https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html]. Unfortunately when i test it with namespaces and actual message, in the online tool its giving me _Saxon is not able to process Microsoft's WD-xsl dialect_ error. Do i have to watch out for some namespaces when applying the logic ?

Comment: True, there is an extra '.' in my namespace that was causing this error. Another question, if i have to do the opposite, i.e if i have to copy the value from child node to parent, how do i do it?  I did a match to element and then copy-of with select= / or // to the xpath, it doesnt produce exact result.

Comment: I suggest you post a separate question with a complete example.